# Add attribute to first item of array in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a select box and want to get the options of an array.

```php
<select class="form-control select-search" name="user_select_crypto" 
        id="user_select_crypto">
    @foreach($currencies as $currency)
        <option value="{{ $currency->id }}">{{ $currency->crypto->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Now, I want to first item add the `selected` attribute, how can I do this?

Comment: There is also a very popular library that handles this very well and can automatically bind: Laravel Collective:  https://www.tutcodex.com/laravel-collective-html-form-builder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of 2 things: Either `$index => $val` approach as classic foreach.

```
@foreach($currencies as $i => $currency)
    <option value="{{ $currency->id }}" {{ $i == 0 ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$currency->crypto->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Also as of more Laravel way, there is `$loop` variable you can access inside blade in `@foreach`

```
@foreach($currencies as $i => $currency)
    <option value="{{ $currency->id }}" {{ $loop->first ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$currency->crypto->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

---

Of course, you can translate `{{ $loop->first ? 'selected' : ''}}` into:

`@if ($loop->first) 'selected' @endif`

Comment: Just to correct you, `$loop->first` instead of `$loop->first()` as `first` is a property and not a function. It will blow up.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, fixing now. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

A better way to deal with such issues is to add a default `<option></option>`;

```
<select class="form-control select-search" name="user_select_crypto" id="user_select_crypto">
    <option value="" selected disabled >Select Currency</option>
    @foreach($currencies as $key => $currency)
    <option value="{{ $currency->id }}">{{$currency->crypto->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```